# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installation problem

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a dynamic disk? (“The request isn't supported” from bcdedit.exe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-dynamic-disk-the-request-isnt-suppor)

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my PC using WUBI. However, I keep getting this error:

An error occured:

```
*Error executing command
>>command=C:\\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {2708afc0-9ffa-11e1-bc51-d167219ffa25} device partition=E:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occured setting the element data.
The request is not supported.
>>stdout=
For more information, please see the logfile:*
```

Logfile:

```
06-11 10:57 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished choose_disk_sizes
06-11 10:57 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running expand_diskimage...
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished expand_diskimage
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_swap_diskimage...
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_swap_diskimage
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running modify_bootloader...
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: New task modify_bcd
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running modify_bcd...
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: modify_bcd Drive(C: hd 51255.1171875 mb free ntfs)
06-11 10:59 ERROR  TaskList: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {2708afc0-9ffa-11e1-bc51-d167219ffa25} device partition=E:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.
>>stdout=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 697, in modify_bcd
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 66, in run_command
Exception: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {2708afc0-9ffa-11e1-bc51-d167219ffa25} device partition=E:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.
>>stdout=
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: New task modify_bcd
06-11 10:59 ERROR  root: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {2708afc0-9ffa-11e1-bc51-d167219ffa25} device partition=E:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.
>>stdout=
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\win32\backend.py", line 697, in modify_bcd
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\utils.py", line 66, in run_command
Exception: Error executing command
>>command=C:\Windows\System32\bcdedit.exe /set {2708afc0-9ffa-11e1-bc51-d167219ffa25} device partition=E:
>>retval=1
>>stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data.
The request is not supported.
>>stdout=
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: New task modify_bcd
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: New task modify_bcd
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished modify_bootloader
06-11 10:59 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist*
```